# JS cannot call function on array items

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I created a function to check an array if the element of the array is divisible by the next item. If not is shall remove the next item from the array.

I created a test array consisting of two arrays. When I loop over them and console.log them they get returned as expected.

When I call my function (deleteItem) in the for loop instead of the console.log it just returns the result of the first array element and not the second. I am really confused and do not understand this. Can anyone please give me a hint what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

```
let testArray = [[240,12, 10, 8,23],[240,12, 10, 8,24]];

function deleteItem(array) {
      if(array.length<=1){
            return array;
      }
      else{
            for(i=0; i<array.length-1;i++) {
                  let changed = true;
                  while(changed){
                        if(array[i]%array[i+1]!=0) {
                              array.splice(i+1,1);
                              i=0;
                              break;
                        }
                        else {changed=false};
                  }
            }
      }
      return array;
}
```

If I only console log it returns both elements as expected:

```
for(i=0;i<testArray.length;i++){
      console.log(  testArray[i]);
      //console.log(deleteItem(  testArray[i]));
}

returns:
[240, 12, 10, 8, 23]
[240, 12, 10, 8, 24]
```

If I use my function it only calls the first array element

```
for(i=0;i<testArray.length;i++){
      console.log(  testArray[i]);
      console.log(deleteItem(  testArray[i]));
}
returns:
[240, 12, 10, 8, 23]
[240, 12]

I expect:
[240, 12, 10, 8, 23]
[240, 12]
[240, 12, 10, 8, 24]
[240, 12]
```

Comment: You are using the same variable "i" in both loops, "i" gets overwritten in the "deleteItem" function. solution: name the variable in one of the loops something else.

Comment: *solution: declare the variable with `for( let i = 0; ...` keyword. And add `"use strict";` in the first line of your code. Which will tell you about similar mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to declare your for-loop variable with a "let".
It works fine as soon as you add the let. (Same inside the deleteItem function)

```
for(let i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++){
      console.log(testArray[i]);
      console.log(deleteItem(testArray[i]));
}
```

There is no problem when you just loop through your testArray and output every element but inside your deleteItem() function, you have another for-loop with a variable named "i" that is not declared locally.

That means:
You start the testArray loop with a global i = 0. Then you call the deleteItem function that also uses the same global i for its for-loop. So after the deleteItem function is done, the global i is set to 4 and the original for-loop condition doesn't hold anymore. That's why the deleteItem function is not called for your second testArray element.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the i to j and understood the scope here. Now it works :) I was sitting hours over it ... :)

Comment: for(j=0;j<testArray.length;j++){
      console.log(testArray[j]);
      console.log(deleteItem(testArray[j]));
}